# Not able to upload product images in the admin in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, image-upload

We have Magento v1.9.0.1.

when we try to upload product images in the admin we get a JSON-related error in the browser console. we checked the error logs but didn't find any specific cause of this error. we have also set the permission to 777 but didn't work.

when we checked the media/catalog/product/import folder we have found some images which had 0byte size. so we have deleted those images and thought if that could help but still, we are getting the same error.

There might be a possibility that the default image uploader was overwritten by some third-party module but we are not able to figure out the exact extension which could be causing this issue. Is there a way to debug this error in a better way? Can anyone suggest any fix for this issue?

Check below screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given your magento version, it could be related to a faulty or missing patch. At some point the security patches removed flash from the image uploader and many people reported similar issues when the patch did not process correctly. You usually have ".rej" files left behind when there's a problem patching. Look for them and see if they relate to ".swf" files.

If so, check this post https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Security-Patches/SUPEE-8788-fails-on-SWF-files/td-p/50421

My patch tool supports this patch and can help you find the patch for your specific version. https://github.com/frosit/magepatch

If this does not help, try "disabling module output" one by one in the system config and see if it behaves different, or post a little more info like the modules you have installed